# How to read file content into a qmake variable and pass it to the compiler?

Tags: qt, qmake

How to read file content into a variable in qmake project file? For example, I'd like to have the contents of `KEY` read from a file and pass it to the compiler:

```
DEFINES += KEY=**some magic and filename here**
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On all platforms, there's a built-in replace function `$$cat`:

```
# set a qmake variable
KEY = "$$cat(/path/to/the/file)"
# propagate the variable to C/C++
DEFINES += "KEY=\"$$KEY\""
```

The effect of this line is the same as if you added the following line at the beginning of every translation unit (mostly a fancy name for a `.cpp` file):

```
#define KEY <contents of the file>
```

Suppose that the file contains a single line:

```
FOO
```

Then:

```
 // source
 qDebug() << KEY;
 // preprocessed source
 qDebug() << "FOO";
```

Comment: If KEY should be treated as a string by your C/C++ code, add single quotes: `DEFINES += "KEY='\"$$KEY\"'"` This avoids that the shell eats the double quotes, yielding some strange error messages about undefined variables or something similar.