# qmake Language, read value from text file, possible?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5, qmake

Here I have a Qt plugin project. In the .pro project file I have

```
TARGET = $$qtLibraryTarget(pluginname)
```

Where `pluginname` will be the name of the artifact produced by the build (.dll/.so/.dylib). As it is, the name is hard coded. I would like to make it more flexible, for example, reading the name from a text file.

Would that be possible? How do I start?

In fact, read value from file is just the first idea that came to mind, other ideas are welcome.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22403605/how-to-read-file-content-into-a-variable-in-qmake-project-file

Comment: Cool! And would it be possible to read that qmake value from a Qt (C++) file?