# Read qmake variable from Qt code, possible?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5, qmake

Questions:

- [qmake Language, read value from text file, possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38962126/qmake-language-read-value-from-text-file-possible)
- [How to read file content into a qmake variable and pass it to the compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22403605/how-to-read-file-content-into-a-variable-in-qmake-project-file)

Address the issue of reading a value from a text file using qmake.

Let's say:

```
NAME = $$cat(../name.txt)
message($$NAME)
```

Code above read content of `name.txt` and put it on `NAME`, then `NAME` gets printed by `message()`function.

I'm thinking in how to access `NAME` from `Qt` (C++) code, i.e. in `main.cpp`. Is that possible? And do something like:

```
qDebug() << NAME;
```

Comment: qmake doesn't (and shouldn't!) pollute the C namespace with defines. If you want to pass NAME onto C/C++, you have to add it to DEFINES. You've already asked that question before and got an answer to it! It was an exact duplicate.

Comment: The answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22404073/1329652