# qmake Language, how to get current folder name?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5, qmake

The question:

[How to read file content into a qmake variable and pass it to the compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22403605/how-to-read-file-content-into-a-qmake-variable-and-pass-it-to-the-compiler/22404073?noredirect=1#comment65308415_22404073)

Address the issue of reading a text file via `qmake`.

Instead of reading a text file, I would like to get current folder (the folder where this file is in) name. How do I do that?

Comment: I haven't tried it but `absolute_path(".")` sounds promising. [More](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-function-reference.html).

Comment: Everyone means something else by "current folder". What folder exactly do you want? Have you looked in qmake documentation at PWD and PWD_OUT variables? Do these documentation entries not answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does [$$PWD](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#pwd) do what you want?

From the documentation:

> The PWD variable specifies the full path leading to the directory
>   containing the current file being parsed. This can be useful to refer
>   to files within the source tree when writing project files to support
>   shadow builds.